# Paperclip/Carrierwave: How do I prevent my images from being uploaded to a nameless folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, carrierwave, filepath

I'm using Paperclip and Carrierwave to upload images to S3. Currently, images for a certain model are being uploaded to a nameless folder in the root of the bucket. How can I ensure the folder they're uploaded to doesn't have an empty name? Here's the relevant code from the Paperclip/Carrierwave initializer

```
fog_credentials = {
  :provider => "AWS",
  :aws_access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
}

# Carrierwave
config.storage = :fog
config.fog_credentials = fog_credentials
config.fog_directory = ENV['AWS_S3_BUCKET']
config.fog_public = true

# Paperclip
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:storage] = :fog
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:fog_credentials] = fog_credentials
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:fog_directory] = ENV['AWS_S3_BUCKET']
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:fog_host] = ENV['AWS_S3_ASSET_HOST']
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ":class/:id_partition/:attachment/:style/:filename"
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = ":url"
```

****Edited****

I forgot to mention that I'm using [spree](https://github.com/spree/spree) which seems to rewrite these options somewhere along the line.

I changed the URL and path options by setting these explicitly

```
Spree::Image.attachment_definitions[:attachment][:url] = "spree/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
Spree::Image.attachment_definitions[:attachment][:path] = "spree/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

whose defaults were both prefixed by a slash. According to this [paperclip-aws gem](https://github.com/igor-alexandrov/paperclip-aws#path),prefixing these options with a slash will create a nameless folder in the root of the bucket.

Comment: You mention you're using both gems - any particular reason? I'd just stick to using `paperclip`

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to mention that I'm using [spree](https://github.com/spree/spree) which seems to rewrite these options somewhere along the line.

I changed the URL and path options by setting these explicitly

```
Spree::Image.attachment_definitions[:attachment][:url] = "spree/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
Spree::Image.attachment_definitions[:attachment][:path] = "spree/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

whose defaults were both prefixed by a slash. According to this [paperclip-aws gem](https://github.com/igor-alexandrov/paperclip-aws#path),prefixing these options with a slash will create a nameless folder in the root of the bucket.